# error: Unable to locate r binary by scanning standard locations

Tags: r, macos, rstudio

Receiving the error: unable to locate r binary by scanning standard locations when trying to open Rstudio on my Mac. I have mac osx. I just downloaded Rstudio - Mac-OS X 10.6+ from rstudio.com

In the terminal the code `ls -l /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/` gives me "no such file or directory"

Rstudio and R 3.3.1 are both in the application folder.

Don't know what to do from here.

Comment: Where did you download R from? The CRAN binaries from https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/ are generally recommended.

Comment: SAVIOR!!! Thank you Kevin!

Comment: Download the latest package from here "https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/" install it and you're good to go :)

Answer (score 19):

You don't have the R compiler installed.
Rstudio does not download it by default.

Just install it from this website:

https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/

Then restart R studio and it is going to work!!